# Building a sql query from listbox values asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, indexing-service

I'm struggling with this problem for quit a while.

This is what I want to do:

I want to build a query for the Windows Indexing Service that should look like this

```
SELECT ... FROM  (TABLE Catalog1..Scope('Deep traversal of "Path1"','Deep traversal of "Path2"') UNION ALL TABLE Catalog2..Scope('Deep traversal of "Path3"')) WHERE ...
```

I get the information from a `<asp:Listbox SelectionMode=multiple>` (which has a file as data-source)

And it comes in the following way:

```
'DisplayNameInListbox1'=Catalog1@Path1;Path2&Catalog2
'DisplayNameInListbox2'=Catalog1@Path1
'DisplayNameInListbox3'=Catalog1@Path1;Path2&Catalog2@Path3
...
```

In one of the Listbox values can be multiple catalogs and multiple values can be selected.
Each catalog can stand alone or be restricted to specified paths(@path;path2)

My attempt:
I tried to store all the information in a `Dictionary<string Catalog, List<string Paths>>`
which works fine if I don't select two values which contain the same catalog name. I also can't just skip a catalog if I already have a key with that name because the path restrictions could be different.

Can anyone help me to find a good way solving this problem? (it would also be possible to change the way the data is stored - I just need to be able to provide it to the Listbox from a file)

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here comes the solution to my problem:

I guess most of the time the simplest solution is the best!

I divided the problem in two parts. Now I first merge the catalogs and paths so every catalog exits only once in the dictionary.

And in the second step I can build the query sequentially :)